# How can I avoid explicit decoding of content?

Tags: python, unicode, urllib2

I understand that `.encode('utf-8')` is necessary.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
url = u'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nîmes'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url.encode('utf-8'))
content = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print type(content)
```

But how do I avoid the `.decode('utf-8')`? After all, the page in question properly declares its encoding in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
url = u'https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nîmes'
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content
text = response.text
assert type(content) == str
assert type(text) == unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your question, you can get the encoding from the headers to avoid hard-coding the encoding:

```
content = response.read().decode(response.headers.getparam('charset'))
```

Comment: I like minimal APIs, but this makes urllib2 a rather incomplete API.